# Compute Instagram shortcode from an image filename

Tags: instagram

Is it possible from an image filename compute a post's shortcode containing this image?

For example, for `130603078_209367414109482_797155749429813539_n.jpg` the expected result is `CIvvID_MEXO`. (https://www.instagram.com/p/CIvvID_MEXO/)